# How do I allow certain gestures to go through a superview to a view below it?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with three image views hangin' around. These image views respond to certain gestures. I want to allow a certain gesture (such as a swipe across the screen) to do an action to all of the imageviews (such as, say, delete them all).

The only way I can think of having the swipe gesture be recognized everywhere on the screen is by overlaying a clear superview that looks for swipe gestures. My problem; however, is that I don't know how to let the superview ignore all other gestures so I can still interact with the imageviews below. Is there an easier way to handle this problem?

Comment: A simple image for clarity? http://imgur.com/nsNP2,kwQC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the gesture to your view's window rather than the view:

```
[self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```